# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo de texto en C# con foreach y agregarlo en labels dinámicos?

Tags: c#, loops

Estoy usando C# y desarrollando una aplicación en WindowsForm con el propósito de crear un Chat con conexión MySQL. Los mensajes se almacenarán en una base de datos, después se volcará al sistema en un TXT, y se irá creando un label de forma dinámica con cada línea del TXT.

Mi problema surge en crear el label de forma dinámica. Estoy usando un bucle ***foreach*** pero no funciona, porque no logro que muestre cada línea:

```cs
sql.sqlcmd("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chat");
int count = int.Parse(sql.sqlcmd_answ);

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("mac.txt"))
{
    int i = 0;
    int p = 62;
    while (i < count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = line;
        lb.Location = new Point(58, p);
        p = p + 30;
        panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
        ++i; 
    }
}
```

El archivo contiene estas líneas:

> ```
> 1222
> 22222
> Chat...
> fxckxd
> fxckxd
> fxck
> ffff
> cambio
> Chat...heya
> 22222
> Xd
> Xd
> DDDD3EEEE
> DDDD
> ```

Pero me genera estos labels:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `foreach` no cambia el valor de la variable `line`, sólo muestra la primera línea en vez de todas.

Comment: ¿Y para qué estás comprobando que `i < count`, si el límite del bucle te lo dará directamente la cantidad de líneas del archivo?

Comment: Va a comprobar las lineas del archivo, ya que son las mismas que el número de lineas de la base de datos.

Comment: Hiciste muy bien en escribir en la consola lo que obtenías en cada iteración del bucle, pero creo que no te fijaste qué se estaba imprimiendo... te hubiese ayudado! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es porque anidaste 2 bucles, cuando en realidad deberías tener 1 solo.

El primer bucle se ejecuta 1 vez por cada línea:

```cs
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("mac.txt"))
```

pero, para cada una de esas líneas, estás ejecutando otro bucle:

```cs
    while (i < count)
```

Es decir, si `count == 14`, el siguiente código se ejecutará 14 veces:

```cs
        // ...
        lb.Text = line;
        // ...
        panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

pero cada una de las 14 veces, `line` sigue conteniendo el mismo valor (de la misma línea leida).

Además, como la variable `p` se reinicia en `62` para cada línea leida, estás ubicando cada uno de los 14 labels para cada una de las líneas por sobre los anteriores.

**¿Cómo solucionarlo?**

Es redundante que utilices como límite la cantidad de registros en la base de datos, si simplemente lo que quieres hacer es generar un label para cada línea del archivo. Simplemente el `foreach` se va a encargar de iterar una vez con cada línea:

```cs
int p = 62; //se inicializa 1 sola vez, fuera del loop

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("mac.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);

    Label lb = new Label();
    lb.Text = line;
    lb.Location = new Point(58, p);
    p = p + 30;
    panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
}
```

Comment: Primero de todo muchas gracias!, ¿Qué método alternativo me recomiendas al File.ReadLines() ? Me gustaría obtener el mejor rendimiento.  ¿A qué se debe este error? http://image.prntscr.com/image/8ee41d1724174d5db66a60a77b91fda4.png

Comment: @JoseAviles fue un error por no revisar antes de publicar. Me había confundido con `File.ReadAllLines`. En cuanto a la eficiencia, en esta etapa te recomendaría seguir tal cual lo estás haciendo, ya que puede no ser lo más eficiente, pero eso no quita que funcione más que bien. Una vez que tengas todo aceitado, si quisieras, podrías evaluar el uso de [StreamReader.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx). Edité la respuesta.